# How to resolve issue of npm lib?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-12.04

I wanted to setup lessc on my ubuntu 12.04.

I have followed these steps.

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.8/node-v0.6.8.tar.gz
tar zxf node-v0.6.8.tar.gz
cd node-v0.6.8/
./configure --prefix=/absolute/path/to/the/virtualenv/
make
make install
```

Now  I am trying to install npm lib with the following command:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

---

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0     33      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--   517
sh: 1: cannot open html: No such file
sh: 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Thanks for ans matt: I tried the same and got error. I have added that command in Q.

Comment: Please try `curl http://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` instead of `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`.

Answer (score 1):

npm domain needs to use www prefix.
So it should be like that way :

```
curl http://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```